# Reading a json file and displaying data in ejs

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

New to programming...probably a stupid question...
I have a users.json file.

```
{
    "User": {
        "userID": [
            {
                "$": {
                    "id": "3"
                },
                "username": [
                    "patient1"
                ],
                "email": [
                    "x@gmail.com"
                ],
                "Role_IDrole": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "Organization": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "Lat": [
                    "59.6567"
                ],
                "Long": [
                    "16.6709"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am requiring it in my routes

```
   var userData = require('../users.json');
```

My route

```
app.get('/doctor', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { 
        res.render('doctortest.ejs', {
            user : req.user,
            data: userData
        });
    });
```

In my views/doctortest.ejs, I simply want to print the "email"

```
 <%data.User.userID.email%>
```

It doesn't show anything. What's going on?

Comment: Try `<%= data.User.userID.email %>` instead, note the `=`.

Comment: Hello Skirtle, Now it prints "Undefined"

Comment: `<%= data.User.userID[0].email[0] %>`

Comment: that worked. thank you :)